JNA's IntByReference in Java Foreign Function & Memory API
I have a native .so library that has the following function:
void foo(void* handle);

It works well in C#:
[DllImport("library.so", CallingConvention = (CallingConvention) 3)]
private static extern void foo(ref IntPtr handle);

// ...

IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
foo(ref handle);

However, I cannot implement it in Java 22 using FFM API:
var LINKER = Linker.nativeLinker();
var SYM_LOOKUP = SymbolLookup.loaderLookup().or(LINKER.defaultLookup());
var FOO = LINKER.downcallHandle(SYM_LOOKUP.find("foo").orElseThrow(), FunctionDescriptor.ofVoid(ADDRESS));

var handle = Arena.global().allocate(ValueLayout.ADDRESS); // is this correct?
FOO.invokeExact(handle);

For some reason, I get std::bad_array_new_length in the native code (unfortunately, I don't have source code of the native library).
In JNA, there is com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference, is there something similar in FFM API?

What happens if you allocate a JAVA_INT? Note ADDEESS will be 8 bytes on a 64bit JVM.

@Slaw Still I got the same error.

@BasilBourque Java 22

Hmm. I don't know C#, but this Q&A suggests you were on the right track using ADDRESS. Though the accepted answer also says that IntPtr.Zero is "effectively NULL (a null pointer)". This other Q&A seems to agree. What happens if you pass MemorySegment.NULL (instead of allocating your own segment)?

Your code looks correct (although you could use Linker.nativeLinker().canonicalLayouts().get("size_t") instead of ADDRESS). But, the pointer you are passing to foo points to uninitialized memory, whereas in the C# code the memory is zero initialized. How foo handles this is up to foo. We can't really tell you much without knowing foo's contract. You might wanna try allocateFrom(ADDRESS, MemorySegment.NULL), instead of allocate.

There is no direct IntByReference equivalent in the FFM API. All pointers are represented as MemorySegment, which do not have a type attached to them.

You need your allocated pointer-size memory to point to an allocated int-size memory somewhere. Whether you allocate the int-size memory or the API you're calling does needs further documentation.

I found the error. Actually I had 2 native methods:
void initHandle(void* handle);
void useHandle(void* handle);

and I need to initialize the handle then use it. I was doing this:
var handle = Arena.global().allocate(ValueLayout.ADDRESS);
INIT_HANDLE.invokeExact(handle);
USE_HANDLE.invokeExact(handle);

It turns out that I had to pass the handle differently in second function:
var handle = Arena.global().allocate(ValueLayout.ADDRESS);
INIT_HANDLE.invokeExact(handle);
USE_HANDLE.invokeExact(handle.get(ValueLayout.ADDRESS, 0));

